# How to tag ec2 instances and resources with IAM user that created them?

Tags: amazon-web-services

For a while, I have used cloudformation and a lambda script to tag EC2 instances, their EBS volumes and network interfaces with the IAM user that created them.  Is there a better way to do this automatically with AWS?

Answer (score 1):

AWS does not maintain a relationship between resources and users that create them.

If a user has sufficient permissions to create resources in an account, then any resources created are associated with the AWS Account rather than the user that created them.

One way to discover such a relationship would be to use **AWS CloudTrail** records, since they reference both the resources involved in API calls and the IAM entity (user, role, etc) that issued the API call.

So, in theory you could:

- Create an **Amazon CloudWatch Events rule** to trigger an AWS Lambda function as new CloudTrail events happen
- The **AWS Lambda function** could look at the event, determine whether it's something of interest (eg a resource was created) and then extract the user information and add it to a tag

It could get a little complex, such as requests coming from IAM Roles associated with Amazon EC2 instances, where it is hard to associate API calls with a "user"

Comment: Yep thats exactly how I'm doing it now with lambda and this cloudwatch rule ```{
            "detail-type": [
              "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
            ],
            "detail": {
              "eventSource": [
                "ec2.amazonaws.com"
              ],
              "eventName": [
                "RunInstances"
              ]
            }
          }```.  I was just curious if there was an even simpler way of doing it.  It also helps when your IAM usernames are something logical like email addresses.

Comment: FYI im only concerned with env where users are the only ones making instances.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, AWS doesn't support tagging resources automatically with IAM principal tags. You have to craft your own solution as described in the previous answer. However, you can find a couple of projects on Github. I have been maintaining the following project, which applies IAM principal tags and session tags to newly created resources.

https://github.com/erhanux/aws-tags